# Iterating an array 2 ways with minimal waiting time (dynamic programming)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

We are given an array of integers size n.
The integers represent a time to finish a certain job.
Two workers need to finish these jobs in the minimal amount of time, though they can't overlap.
Say the array given is size 4, the numbers are 1,2,4,5. The first worker does the jobs in order[1] [4] [2] [3], the second one in order [2] [3] [4] [1]. SO the least amount of time taken to do these jobs is 12 units because there is no overlapping.

If the array is size 3, and the numbers 1, 2, 4. The first worker does jobs in order [1][2][3], and the second in order[3][1][2], but there is a problem. Once the first worker finishes job 2(3 units of time has passed), the second one is still doing job 3, so the first worker has to wait for 1 unit in order for the second worker to finish his job. So the least amount of time taken to do these jobs is 1+2+4+1unit waiting = 8 units.

Can I get an idea of what kind of approach to take on this problem? I am using c++

Comment: *Can I get an idea of what kind of approach to take on this problem ? I am using c++* -- The question has nothing to do with C++.  It is an algorithm question, and is not tied to any language.  It requires you to write down a plan of how to solve the problem -- once you have that, *then* the issue of how to implement that plan in C++ (or whatever language) becomes involved.

Answer (score 0):

in this question we have to allocate the work to the the worker A and worker B in such a way tha the waiting time is minimum.

the best case of this problem is to allocate the work with time (total time)/2 to first and the remainimg work to another worker. but we cannot do this because one work is done by only one person.

so we we will find the subset of work whose total time is nearest to the half of total time in this way we can minimize the waiting time.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int dp[1001][1001];

int fun(int arr[],int n,int t,int sum)
{
if(n==0 || sum==0)
return t;

if(dp[n][t]!=-1)
return dp[n][t];


if(t+arr[n-1]<=sum)
{
  return dp[n][t]=max(fun(arr,n-1,t+arr[n-1],sum),fun(arr,n-1,t,sum));
}

else
return dp[n][t]=fun(arr,n-1,t,sum);

}
int main()
{

int size;
cin>>size;

int arr[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
cin>>arr[i];

int total=0;

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
total+=arr[i];

memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
int lower=fun(arr,size,0,total/2);

int ans= lower+(total-lower)+abs(lower-(total-lower));
cout<<ans<<endl;

return 0;
}
```